# Etymology of "переборщить"

Tags: этимология

What is the origin of "**переборщить**"?

I really do doubt it has something in common with Russian soup **борщ**. Another hypothesis was that it is somehow related to "**перебор**" in this meaning:

> Derived from the verb **перебрать**:
>
> Взять, набрать лишку. Вы перебрали жалованья за прошлый месяц десять
>   рублей. У вас пайковой дачи перебрано лишку.
>
> В. Даль Толковый словарь живого великорусского языка
>
> ПЕРЕБО́Р, переборка, муж. (разг.).
>   1. Излишек чего-нибудь, взятый сверх надлежащего количества. Перебор по текущему счету.
>   2. Излишнее количество очков на взятых игроком картах (карт.).
>   3. Механизм токарного станка, служащий для уменьшения скорости вращения шпинделя (тех.).
>
> Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940.

However, then there is one contradiction (maybe it actually isn't, what do you think?) : the continuous form of **переборщить** is **перебарщивать**, o there is actually vowel alternation in the stem ( **а - о**), whereas in cognate words of **перебор** there is another type of gradation (**и - о - выпадение**).

In search for the answer I found materials on:

- [ответы Гугл](http://otvety.google.ru/otvety/thread?tid=098f2493d7a269bb);
- gramota.ru  ( it seems that I share Chernykh's opinion ):

> Связь слов переборщить и борщ  не исключена: в словаре В. И. Даля
>   дается слово борщить, которое в южных диалектах означает 'лить через
>   край, слишком много'. Впрочем, П. Я. Черных в
>   «Историко-этимологическом словаре русского языка» указывает: «Что
>   касается глаг. переборщить – перебарщивать, то это позднее неуклюжее
>   новообразование, известное лишь с начала XX в., происходит,
>   по-видимому, не от борщ, а... от переборка, ср. далее перебрать».

What is your opinion on the etymology of this word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Похоже все-таки у выражения есть украинские корни. В [Национальном корпусе](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%EF%E5%F0%E5%E1%EE%F0%F9%E8%F2%FC&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=) нашелся такой пример:

> ― Вы мою просьбу переборщили, Карло Осипович. Я просил вас рекомендовать для детей наших учителя только не бойкого, а вы привезли какого-то дида. [Т. Г. Шевченко. Близнецы (1855)]

Это самый первый пример употребления этого выражения. Автор "Близнецов" - Тарас Шевченко - классик украинской литературы и скорее всего он отразил реально бытовавшее в то время на Украине выражение. Следующий случай употребления относится к 1900 году, так что конкурентов у Шевченко не наблюдается.

Сама цитата содержит несколько украинских "акцентов": "дид" - украинская версия слова "дед". "Карло Осипович" - пример украинского звательного падежа, причем Осип - распространенное в те времена украинское имя, производное от библейского Иосиф.

Интересен график употребления этого слова по годам. Первый пик - это цитата из Шевченко, потом затишье до 1900. После 1900 и до 1917 зафиксировано 6 употреблений.

[image: Распределение "переборщить" по годам]

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion it's a made up word. It's just a combination of `перебор` and `борщ`.
Похоже на [народную этимологию](http://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Thanks =) This is a very nice answer. As nobody has so far provided a more documented one, I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1):

You are a quite right. But "Borscht" is Ukrainian national soup that is popular in many Eastern countries and especially in Ukraine and Russia. One of its main ingredients in the past was Heracleum(in Ukrainian its name is "борщівник(borschtshyivnyk)" or just "борщ(borshth"). So "переборщить" means put a little bit more parts of Heracleum(борщ) that it's necessary into Ukrainian soup Borshcht . When Borscht and the word "переборщить" came into Moscow Country the word "переборщить" became to be used in meaning "do it a little bit wrong"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heracleum_(plant)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borscht

Comment: Please tell us where does your information come from. You may be stretching a bit.